# WinForms bold label displays correctly in Visual Studio Designer but gets squished when running the application

Tags: c#, winforms, label, visual-studio-2022, windows-forms-designer

As illustrated in the screenshot below, a normal WinForms label works fine in both the Designer and the running application, but a bold label will get distorted after a certain point in the running app. I haven't changed any default properties on the labels except for setting the font style to bold for the second label. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to add **`Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);`** to `Program.cs`. I though that it was added by default since Visual Studio 2015, but I forgot to check and the project I was working on predates the automatic inclusion of this line by the IDE.